# Swift Apple Pay Crashes; PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController = nil

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode6, stripe-payments, applepay

I am trying to implement Apple Pay into my app. I've setup my merchant ID twice and I've installed Stripe, Stripe-Apple Pay via CocoaPods. Every time I try to run the app on my device it crashes. I've added breakpoints to try and understand where the error is occurring and I see the following when I get to the code
`applePayController.delegate = self`

```
request PKPaymentRequest    0x00000001700f3180  0x00000001700f3180
applePayController  PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController!   nil None
```

Then the app crashes and I get this error message

```
function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded> 
of Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #2)
->  0x100581474 <+44>:  brk    #0x1
```

Can someone help me figure out how to resolve this issue. Here is my code

```
import UIKit
import PassKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

let SupportedPaymentNetworks = [PKPaymentNetworkVisa, PKPaymentNetworkMasterCard, PKPaymentNetworkAmex]
let ApplePayMerchantID = "merchant.com.Flokk.FlokkV33"

var currentObject : PFObject?

@IBOutlet var EventName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var EventTime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var VenueName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Location: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Description: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var EventImage: PFImageView!
@IBOutlet var PayButton: UIButton!

var ticketValue:NSDecimalNumber = 0.99

@IBAction func purchase(sender: AnyObject) {

    let request = PKPaymentRequest()
    let applePayController = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request)
    applePayController.delegate = self

//
    presentViewController(applePayController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    request.merchantIdentifier = ApplePayMerchantID
    request.supportedNetworks = SupportedPaymentNetworks
    request.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability.Capability3DS
    request.countryCode = "US"
    request.currencyCode = "USD"

    request.paymentSummaryItems = [
        PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Test Ticket", amount: ticketValue),
        PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Flokk Event", amount: ticketValue)
    ]


}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    PayButton.hidden = !PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks(SupportedPaymentNetworks)

    if let object = currentObject {
        EventName.text = object["EventName"] as? String
        Description.text = object["EventDescription"] as? String
        VenueName.text = object["EventVenueName"] as? String
        Location.text = object["EventLocation"] as? String
        Description.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

        var initialImage = UIImage(named: "DidNotLoad")
        EventImage.image = initialImage
        if let parseEventPhoto = object["EventImage"] as? PFFile{
            EventImage.file = parseEventPhoto
            EventImage.loadInBackground()
        }

}

        }
}
extension DetailViewController: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate {
    func paymentAuthorizationViewController(controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController!, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment!, completion: ((PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus) -> Void)!) {
        completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.Success)
    }

    func paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish(controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController!) {
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you checking for a `nil` `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController`? From the Apple documentation `If the user can’t make payments on any of the payment request’s supported networks, initialization fails and this method returns nil`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to move:

```
let applePayController = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request)
presentViewController(applePayController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

at the end of the `purchase(sender: AnyObject)` function.

In other words, first create and configure your payment request and then create `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController`